# Creating a dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary of the following type:

```
inpt = {1011: .12,
        1012: .43,
        1013: .33,
        1014: .54,
        1112: .4,
        1113: .32,
        1114: .76,
        1213: .54,
        1214: .544,
        1314: .44,
       }
```

I want to convert it to a following dataframe:

```
      | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  |
 | 10 | .01 | .12 | .43 | .33 | .54 | 
 | 11 | .12 |  01 | .4  | .32 | .76 | 
 | 12 | .43 | .4  |  1  | .54 | .54 | 
 | 13 | .33 | .32 | .54 |  1  | .44 | 
 | 14 | .54 | .76 | .54 | .44 |  1  |
```

Comment: Please post your data as raw text instead of an image, so we can copy and paste it. Also, what is the rationale behind the diagonal? It's nowhere in your data and it seems to be different in different spots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and combine the output with itself after transposing the values:

```
inpt = {1011: .12,
        1012: .43,
        1013: .33,
        1014: .54,
        1112: .4,
        1113: .32,
        1114: .76,
        1213: .54,
        1214: .544,
        1314: .44,
       }

# set up initial DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': inpt})

# split the 4 digits into 2 + 2 (other methods are possible)
df.index, df['col'] = np.divmod(df.index, 100)
# df.index, df['col'] = df.index.astype(str).str.extract('(..)(..)')

# reshape and combine with transpose
out = df.pivot(columns='col', values='value')
out = out.combine_first(out.T).fillna(1)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
      10    11     12    13     14
10  1.00  0.12  0.430  0.33  0.540
11  0.12  1.00  0.400  0.32  0.760
12  0.43  0.40  1.000  0.54  0.544
13  0.33  0.32  0.540  1.00  0.440
14  0.54  0.76  0.544  0.44  1.000
```